# Go: How to Manage Nested Templates?

Tags: templates, go, nested

Trying to use templates in a sane way, but I think I'm holding it wrong.

Base Template is

```
{{define "base"}}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
{{template "head" .}}
{{template "meta" . }}

</head>
<body>
<!-- some html -->
    {{template "body" .}}   
</body>
```

Page Template is

```
{{define "head"}}<title>{{.Title}}</title>{{end}}
{{define "body"}}<h2>{{.Title}}</h2>

<p>{{.Content}}</p>

{{end}}
```

I can output the template like so

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "html/template"
)

func singleHandler(db *sql.DB, r *gin.Engine) gin.HandlerFunc {

    return gin.HandlerFunc(func(c *gin.Context) {

        html := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/_base.tmpl", "templates/single.tmpl", "templates/meta.tmpl"))
        r.SetHTMLTemplate(html)

// get data from database

        data := struct {
            E *model.E
            M []model.M
        }{
            e,
            m,
        }

        c.Render(200, c.Engine.HTMLRender, "base", data)
    })
}
```

But this means that if I add some template for some other block of content in the future, I'll have to go through all other files and add in the new template into template.ParseFiles(…). Also, I'd have to add in all the new code for filling in that template's data into every module that's supposed to do something else.

What's the intended way of structuring modules and nested templates?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Add a comment line like `"templates/_base.tmpl", "templates/single.tmpl", "templates/meta.tmpl"` at the begin of base template.

Read the template files string and pass them to `template.ParseFiles()` dynamically.

Comment: thanks, but that looks like a somewhat fragile workaround. isn't there a more robust pattern to apply to this very common problem?